# How to retain the task of the activity even when closing the app Android

Tags: android, task, retain

I have a switch button in my android app I intend to switch it on but after I exit the app by removing it on my background task when I opened again the app it goes back to normal and switch goes back to off again. i=I want to retain or save the activity which I have been left. How am I going to retain the task of my activity basically the fragment itself? Am I going to use On pause?

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using shared preferences. For example, in `onCreate`, load the switch state from shared preferences (with a default for the first time)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyUniquePrefsName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
switchState = prefs.getBoolean("MyBoolean", false); // switchState being a boolean class member
// then set the switch to switchState
```

When the user updates the switch, change the stored value of `switchState` and in `onPause` save the updated state to the shared preferences

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("MyUniquePrefsName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    ed.putBoolean("MyBoolean", switchState);
    ed.apply();
}
```